# Else if option 3 does not produce answer...what did I do wrong?

Tags: c, if-statement, user-defined-functions, equation, udf

The program runs but I can't figure out why the function within the third 
else if statement doesn't return an accurate value. Thank you for the help in
advance.

```
finaltemp = newtemp(t, choice);

printf("\nThe converted temperature is: %f", finaltemp);

return(0);
}

double newtemp(double a, double b)
{
double result;
if (b==1)
  {
    result = (a-(273.15));
  }
if (b==2)
  {
    result = (a+(273.15));
  }
if (b==3)
  {
    result = (((5/9)*(a))-32);
  }
if (b==4)
  {
    result = (((9/5)*(a))+32);
  }
if (b==5)
  {
    result = (((9/5)*(a))-459.67);
  }
if (b==6)
  {
    result = ((a+459.67)*(9/5));
  }

 return(result);
 }
```

Comment: Where is " the third else if statement"? I see no `else` in your posted code.

Comment: @MikeCAT I didn't format it in the post correctly so the 'else' part of the statement was cut off. Anyway the mistake I made was using int division rather than floating point division. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're performing integer division, not floating point division.

The expression `(5/9)` divides two `int` values, so the result is an `int`, specifically 0.  You need to use floating point constants to force floating point division.

```
if (b==3)
  {
    result = (((5.0/9.0)*(a))-32);
  }
if (b==4)
  {
    result = (((9.0/5.0)*(a))+32);
  }
if (b==5)
  {
    result = (((9.0/5.0)*(a))-459.67);
  }
if (b==6)
  {
    result = ((a+459.67)*(9.0/5.0));
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I actually realized what I was doing wrong after staring at it for 30 minutes. Such a silly oversight. Thanks for the explanation as well!